# Why is only one object being rendered?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So I am working on something based on a tutorial [Blender Beginner Tutorial: Create a Lightsaber - 2 of 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6lSfOfiXHY).
I am trying to finish my project and render it, but it only renders the main object (image 2), which is the lightsaber. It wont render the laser or the ground.
Although I can see this in the render preview (image 1)
What can/do I have to do to change this?

image 1 (render preview)
[image: render preview]

image 2 (complete render)
[image: complete render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your objects renderability in the outliner, see if any of them are set to visible in the viewport but not renderable.

I also notice you have objects in different scene layers, turn them all on before rendering.

Are you also using any render layers? Check your are rendering all render layers and if all objects are assigned to render in at least one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much! Somehow pretty much all of my objects moved to another layer without me noticing. Now it rendered it how it is supposed to be. :)
What a great community. You almost answered immediately. I could kiss you right now.^^ It's 4 a.m. here and I was so frustrated, that it didn't work (I am a beginner in blender!)