# Why isn't my sapling rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, bezier-curves, sapling-addon

I have set up a fairly simple scene and have gone through the process of making and animating a sapling. I left it as a curve and applied a material to it. When I hit render, the tree doesn't show at all.

[image]

[image: Note that the 'tree' object is NOT the tree I want rendered. That's why it is unviewable and urenderable]

Note that the 'tree' object is NOT the tree I want rendered. That's why it is unviewable and urenderable

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using cycles, and even if it is a material problem, the tree should still render just as a blank thing, right? Is there something special I have to do in order for curves to render?

---

UPDATE

The tree renders fine in rendered view port.

---

Here is a stripped version of the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Check if your tree object is set to unrenderable in the outliner (little camera icon). Otherwise edit your question and provide more information like screenshots your settings and object properties. Also check animation/armature settings, see if they are not interfering with the object at the current frame.

Comment: Your tree *curve* has a disabled rendering option. As Duarte Farrajota Ramos said you need to click the **little camera icon** next to the curve in the *outliner* to make it renderable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is only one object being rendered?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47240/why-is-only-one-object-being-rendered)

Comment: @PaulGonet If these screenshots were taken at the same time, you can't actually see the selected tree. That is a different tree, but the selected one is a child of "treeArm".

Comment: @Daniel Can you [post a blend?](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: @PaulGonet I put a note underneath that particular picture stating that that is NOT the tree object I am using which is why it is unchecked.

Comment: @pycoder my file is too large.

Comment: @Daniel It may be too large as it is, but just keep stripping out pieces that aren't related to your problem until it is a reasonable size. Also make sure to not include any packed textures. Doing this alone will probably solve your problem, but if not, it'll be easy to see the issues once it is uploaded.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3tf6fnoyol30vty/AAC7dFZvCWETAp8_F3KvQOkva?dl=0    @pycoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the layer it is on is disabled for the active blender layer:

[image]

Enable the box the arrow is pointing at.

Comment: Of course it's something stupid easy like this! I feel like an idiot for not checking!